# How Facebook, Slack or other social networks recognize page content?

Tags: node.js, facebook, algorithm

I'm wondering how Facebook, Google, Slack or any other social network recognizes the content of a currently posted page? 
Anytime, when you add a link to some page (for example photo page) it will automatically create a preview with an image and title of that page...

I'm trying to create similar functionality by using NodeJS...

Any idea?
Tnx.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `<meta>` tags with `og:` in them in the source of [that page](https://500px.com/photo/203795373/group-of-friends-having-fun-on-the-seashore-by-cristian-negroni):

```
<meta content='Group of friends having fun on the seashore' property='og:title'>
<meta content='Group of friends having fun on the seashore' property='og:description'>
<meta content='https://drscdn.500px.org/photo/203795373/q%3D80_m%3D2000_k%3D1/a91b87d68203d5306a1e857494a0662e' property='og:image'>
```

They’re part of the [Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/), and you can look for Open Graph packages on npm. Here’s one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/open-graph

Comment: Thank you so much!
Btw.. do you know why this url doesn't work with og:? It has those metas...

http://www.photosight.ru/photos/6540292/?from=top%2F50

Comment: @EugeneVilder: It has `name="og:title"` instead of `property="og:title"`.